# Camera gets lag when waiting for readline from arduino to python

Tags: python, opencv, arduino

I am working with a real time image processing, where in my camera is actively detecting tomatoes in a conveyor. What I am trying to do is to print the object detected in python from the real time image processing whenever the IR is triggered in the conveyor. Delay is about 500ms-1s every time.

i am working in PC, i7-8750H processor and Logitech c922 Camera.

arduino code when the IR is triggered:

```
delay(1000);
Serial.println("1");
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
rotateClockwise();  
delay(1000);
```

my config for arduino is:

```
arduino = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)
```

this is my code in reading the trigger of IR sensor in arduino

```
msg = arduino.readline().strip(32)
    print(str(msg))
    if (msg.decode('utf-8') == "1"):
        display_data()
```

Is there any way that I can reduce/remove the lag of the camera?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Your post lacks some important information. How long is the delay. What do you send with your Arduino? provide the code! Is your Python/OpenCV running on a PC?...

Comment: but you have a 1000ms delay befor you send the 1 via serial? so why are you confused about having a delay? I don't understand your question

Comment: That delay is to stop the conveyor and lets the python to have time in printing the value, but even if i remove it, Camera still gets lag.

Comment: and where does it occur? in the serial part or after? you did not provide any camera code so I assume the delay happens befor your print msg?